# SSIS Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I'm trying to run the following Poweshell command via SSIS using the following argument..

```
(get-content z:\2.html) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "><", ">`r`nE<"} | set-content z:\2.html
```

This works in Powershell at the command line, but I cannot get this to work in SSIS.

I get the error

```
at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

In SSIS I have :

```
1. Created an "Execute process Task"
2. Pointed the Executable to system32\WIndowsPowershell .. etc
3. Added the argument as detailed above using a variable as the filename
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want to run powershell script in SSIS? What is your next step with z:\2.html?

Comment: I'm adding line breaks in an HTML file which contains tables. I then read to extract data from these tables. I can do this in a script once I have the line breaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the syntax should have been....

```
(get-content z:\3.html) | foreach-object {$_ -replace '><', '>`r`nE<'} | set-content z:\3.html
```

it works now!

Comment: @MigueIH please accept this answer even if it is yours, so question will be marked as answered